# Prevent content editors from adding "$" to field

Tags: cartthrob, custom-fields

I'm using CarthThrob and a modify by quantity price field (CartThrob Price - Quantity). What it does:

1-3 = $5

3-9999 = $4

It lets you set a lower price as you buy more. Nice feature, but the people entering the data are adding a $ before the prices. You need to enter just the digits: 5 not $5. If the $ is added it breaks the order total calculations. All kinds of weird stuff happens, mainly the effected products are free.

How can I prevent users from entering the $ value? The setting on the field don't let me choose numeric and the CT docs don't mention this little (Big) problem.

Comment: Put instructions in the field telling them not to enter a $. Let your client know that's how it works. Report the bug to CT.

Comment: Big bold "Just the Digits, no $" didn't help. Nor did the one-on-one training I gave them. arghhh. I can report it to CT, but these days thats not worth much.

Comment: They're getting their act together - worth a shot anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If your site is in HTML5, try using patterns. This answer assumes you have template-level control over the form you provide people for the price, as in Safecracker (but you'll have to explicitly code your forms, and NOT use the {display_field} inside the custom_fields loop.)

`<input type="text" placeholder="" name="" pattern="[0-9]* value="{cf_name}">`

or perhaps

`<input type="number" etc="etc" pattern="[0-9]*>`

Comment: It is in the CP, not front end via Safecracker.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround it with JS - either via a custom accessory or, easier, the CP Add CSS/JS Add-on:

Install the CP CSS & JS add-on from here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css and put this in the settings for Custom JavaScript:

```
if ($('.cartthrobPriceQuantityThresholds').length){
    $('.cartthrobPriceQuantityThresholds input').blur(function(){
        $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[$]/g, '') );
    });   
}
```

Done.